# Spring Boot with Javascript for Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, spring-boot, single-page-application

I am new to MVC. Please bear with me.

I know Thymeleaf is the preferred way of developing MVC application with spring. In this way, you have the index.html inside of src/main/resources/templates.

I want a similar experience but with a javascript framework. Is that possible? (what is that even called).

I have been looking into vue.js as Angular 4 looks very "bloated" and heavy.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? You can use javascript with thymeleaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spring boot with Angular or any other SPA frameworks. There are more than just one approach, but I think the most common is creating RESTFul services using spring boot and these services will be consumed by an Angular or other JavaScript app.

I use to create React Apps that talks with services created in Java (using Spring Boot). All data transfer between back and front end is handle by JSON files.

Hope it helps to clarify your ideas.

Comment: any tutorial you would recommend to do this with angular or whatever framework is easiest to learn (I was concentrating on vuejs as it seems very approachable )

Comment: To create a web service you can start [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). I haven't used VueJs yet, but it seems to be a very good option. This [article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/rest-api-axios/) can be a good start.